# Is it possible to arrange the 2 or 3 items of Enum Property in one row and others is second or third?

Tags: python, panel

I have an enum property that has 6 items and what I want is to arrange the 3 items in one and the other 3 items in the second row. Is it possible to set them?

Here is the code:

```
class NEW_PT_CUSTOM_73B8D(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = 'Custom'
    bl_idname = 'SNA_PT_CUSTOM_73B8D'
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_context = ''
    bl_category = 'Sell'
    bl_order = 0
    bl_ui_units_x=0

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
#        col = layout.column()
        layout.prop(bpy.context.scene, 'my_enum', expand=True)


def register():
    bpy.types.Scene.my_enum = bpy.props.EnumProperty(name='enum', description='', items=[('Rocket', 'Rocket', '', 0, 0), ('Jeep', 'Jeep', '', 0, 1), ('Truck', 'Truck', '', 0, 2), ('Car', 'Car', '', 0, 3), ('Bike', 'Bike', '', 0, 4), ('Plane', 'Plane', '', 0, 5)])
    try: bpy.utils.register_class(NEW_PT_CUSTOM_73B8D)
    except: pass


def unregister():
    del bpy.types.Scene.my_enum
    try: bpy.utils.unregister_class(NEW_PT_CUSTOM_73B8D)
    except: pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: On an enum you will not be able to have a mixed organization of the items.
If you really want that layout create 2 local enum properties in your custom panel and change your global property thanks to an override of the set and get functions of those local items.

Comment: You are going too far. I'm new if you could please write a code for me that would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `layout.prop_enum(context.scene, "my_enum", "Rocket")` [link](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UILayout.html?highlight=layout%20prop%20enum#bpy.types.UILayout.prop_enum) you can adress single enum items in layout. Third data is the item.identifier. See script.

To be more flexible, for example because of dynamically generated enum properties, we can reach the single items with `bl_rna.properties["my_enum"].enum_items`. In second example the enum items are looped and placed in row. Next row after third element.

```
import bpy

class NEW_PT_CUSTOM_73B8D(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = 'Custom'
    bl_idname = 'SNA_PT_CUSTOM_73B8D'
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_context = ''
    bl_category = 'Sell'
    bl_order = 0
    bl_ui_units_x=0

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
#        col = layout.column()
        layout.prop(bpy.context.scene, 'my_enum', expand=True)

        # first example
        layout.separator(factor=2) 
        row = layout.row(align=True)
        row.prop_enum(context.scene, "my_enum", "Rocket")        
        row.prop_enum(context.scene, "my_enum", "Jeep")        
        row.prop_enum(context.scene, "my_enum", "Truck")        
        row = layout.row(align=True)        
        row.prop_enum(context.scene, "my_enum", "Car")        
        row.prop_enum(context.scene, "my_enum", "Bike")        
        row.prop_enum(context.scene, "my_enum", "Plane")          
        
        # second example  
        layout.separator(factor=2) 
        row = layout.row(align=True)
        for index, item in enumerate(context.scene.bl_rna.properties["my_enum"].enum_items):   
            row.prop_enum(context.scene, "my_enum", item.identifier)
            if index == 2: # new line after third item
                row = layout.row(align=True)            


def register():
    bpy.types.Scene.my_enum = bpy.props.EnumProperty(name='enum', description='', items=[('Rocket', 'Rocket', '', 0, 0), ('Jeep', 'Jeep', '', 0, 1), ('Truck', 'Truck', '', 0, 2), ('Car', 'Car', '', 0, 3), ('Bike', 'Bike', '', 0, 4), ('Plane', 'Plane', '', 0, 5)])
    try: bpy.utils.register_class(NEW_PT_CUSTOM_73B8D)
    except: pass


def unregister():
    del bpy.types.Scene.my_enum
    try: bpy.utils.unregister_class(NEW_PT_CUSTOM_73B8D)
    except: pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is more than I was thinking.

Comment: Thank you @relaxed, this use of prop_enum is very interesting (and new for me).
It is sad that this one, all along with some other methods, is not properly documented.